# PHP_SESSION_DISABLED with enabled Session Support

Tags: php, html, session

I'm during making a website with some php for my classes and I really need to use sessions. The thing is, `session_status()` keeps returning PHP_SESSION_DISABLED. I've been looking everywhere on the internet but all I've found was variations of [this article](https://support.qualityunit.com/021373-How-To-Enable-Session-Support-for-PHP). On the server we are supposed to work on all these settings are the same as in the article except for `session.save_path` which is set to /var/lib/php5. The article says the path "*should be under 777 chmod*" and so I tried to change it to "/tmp" but with no help. Here's the code I'm trying to get to work:

```
<?php
    session_save_path("/tmp");
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['message'] = "session disabled";
    if(session_status == PHP_SESSION_DISABLED)
        echo $_SESSION['message'];
?>
```

I keep it at the very beggining of the page and it keeps printing "session disabled". Meanwhile `phpinfo()` shows that Session Support is enabled. There's a lot of settings so I'm not pasting them all here. Am I doing something wrong?

Also I just noticed that there is a file called sess_logIn in the /tmp directory and "logIn" is an id I tried to set for the session at some point. But it's rights are rw------- and it's owner is called www-data. But I don't seem to be able to create other session files in there.

Comment: Any errors? Also what does `session_start()` return?

Comment: It returns the value 1

Comment: `1` means true which means the session is starting just fine. I don't know if `session_status()` would work properly after the session has started (it's kind of a moot point)

Comment: Also make sure you're using the `()` in `session_status()` it's not in your shared code.

Comment: Well, after I put the parentheses, it returns PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE. I would swear I tried with them before. Wish I could accept your answer. Thanks a lot!

Comment: `session_id()` gives proper value too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The suggested way to handle a session:

```
// Session config goes here...
session_save_path("/tmp");
if (session_status() != PHP_SESSION_DISABLED) {
    session_start();
} else {
    die("Sessions are disabled. Sorry");
 }
 //Session is alive and well here could double check using if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE)
```